# require('child_process').execFile() does not work?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, flask, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a web application build with flask and would like to make it into a desktop application with the help of nw.js (also known as node-webkit).

I found online that to be able to do so I need to write a script which executes the python script and then loads the homepage.

In my case the python script is called 'db_app.py' and the homepage is called 'login.html'.

This is my code.

```
<script>

var gui = require('nw.gui');

var currentWindow = gui.Window.get(); // Get reference to loading.html

var exec = require('child_process');
exec.execFile('db_app.py', {cwd:'.'}, function (error, stdout, stderr){ 

var appWindow = gui.Window.open('templates/login.html', // Starts your    application
   { width: 800,
     height: 600,
     position: 'center',
     focus: false,
     transparent: false // This hides the application window
   }
);
appWindow.on('loaded', function() { // Waits for application to be loaded
   currentWindow.close({force: 'true'}); // Closes loading.html
     appWindow.show();  // Shows app.html
     appWindow.focus(); // Set the focus on app.html
});
});

</script>
```

My problem is that the python script does not run. The login.html page loads up but the python code has no effect.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try `db_app.py` in your command prompt/terminal? Chances are it doesn't know how to open it.

Comment: @BenFortune the code runs and if I go on localhost:5000/login the page comes up as it is supposed to

Comment: Try setting it to `python db_app.py`. If that doesn't work then it's most likely an issue of PATH variables not being set. Are you checking `error`, `stdout` or `stderr` for output?

Comment: I know its a newby question but, How do I check the error, stdout or stderr output?

Comment: exec() and execFile() return an Error object in case of error so you can just: if(error !== null){ console.log(error);}

Comment: Why are you doing `cwd: '.'`?  I would expect that to, at best, be a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because execFile is not creating a shell so it doesn't know how to find the python interpreter. Try:

```
exec.exec('python db_app.py', {cwd:'.'},function(..){..})
```

Comment: I've updated my answer please check now. execFile does not execute a subshell, exec does so it should run python without problems

Comment: When I do exec I suddenly get a long error. Its too long to write it on here.

Comment: The end of the message said:

[Errno 48] Address already in use\n"", source: file:///Users/ShEsKo/Downloads/libfromage/trunk/db_app/load.html (13)

Comment: Can it be it's an error from your python script? Can you create a simple script to confirm? Just one line would be ok like: print ('test script')

Comment: Yes, I believe its a problem with my script now. You solved my initial problem. Thank you very much :)